# Want to know target url when WebChromeClient#onCreateWindow is called

Tags: android

When i tap a hyperlink with `target="_blank"` `attributes`, `WebChromeClient#onCreateWindow` is called but i cannot find a way to now what url the new window will open? host page url is the only thing i can know?

I want to change the app behavior according to the target url. any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I am late to the party but none of the above solution worked for me on Android 10. So here's how I did it:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg) {
    WebView newWebView = new WebView(view.getContext());
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(newWebView);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
    newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request.getUrl().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
            if (url != null && !url.isEmpty()) {
               // HERE IS URL WHICH YOU WANT
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Android 11 here and yours is the solution that worked for me

Comment: This solution works even for the case where new window is created by JavaScript instead of a link. Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

## SOLVED

i could get clicked url by calling like as follows

```
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
    int type = result.getType();
    String data = result.getExtra();
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This works, but if I have an <img> tag nested inside <a href> tag, then I only get the <img> tag src location.    How do I get the value of the location mentioned in 'href' attribute?

Comment: Actually, i found that this works only for single <a> tag. For now i didn't found the solution for that case.

Comment: For images inside `a` tags use `WebView.requestFocusNodeHref` method.

Comment: Note that a URL may not be enough, even if you manage to obtain it. The original and the new window, may need to exchange messages (the same way browser tabs can communicate with each other). In that case it seems you have to use the recommended approach of `resultMessage.obj.setWebView(newWebView); resultMessage.sendToTarget();` and open the new webview in the same activity as the original webview.

Comment: No longer works as of Android 11, always get `null`. See the answer by @Mustansir

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code:

```
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    Message href = view.getHandler().obtainMessage();
    view.requestFocusNodeHref(href);           
    var url = href.getData()?.getString("url");

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: great..! works as expected

Answer (score 3):

following snippet will do the work.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow (WebView view,boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg){
        //The default implementation
        //return super.onCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
        //This way you can get the URL
        String url = null;
        if (webView.getHitTestResult().getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE
               || webView.getHitTestResult().getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
            url = webView.getHitTestResult().getExtra();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

[source](https://www.programmersought.com/article/30814057230/)